# Why doesn't DataFrameReader have "avro" method to read avro files?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I see that the [DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) have methods to read parquest, ORC etc. file types but not Avro. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because parquet and orc are built-in data sources. If you are using Scala, you can use [Spark Avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) and import `com.databricks.spark.avro._`, then you will get `avro` method which is implemented via Scala implicit class.